# Getting documents with ID from firstore collection

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire, vue-tables-2

While using Firestore, vuefire, vue-tables-2, I stuck getting document's id.

My data structure is as below.
[image]

Here is my code.

```
  <v-client-table :columns="columns" :data="devices" :options="options" :theme="theme" id="dataTable">


 import { ClientTable, Event } from 'vue-tables-2'
  import { firebase, db } from '../../firebase-configured'

  export default {
    name: 'Devices',
    components: {
      ClientTable,
      Event
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        devices: [],
        columns: ['model', 'id', 'scanTime', 'isStolen'],
        options: {
          headings: {
            model: 'Model',
            id: 'Serial No',
            scanTime: 'Scan Time',
            isStolen: 'Stolen YN'
          },
          templates: {
            id: function(h, row, index) {
                return index + ':' + row.id  // <<- row.id is undefined
            },
            isStolen: (h, row, index) => {
                return row.isStolen ? 'Y': ''
            }
          },
          pagination: {
            chunk: 5,
            edge: false,
            nav: 'scroll'
          }
        },
        useVuex: false,
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
        template: 'default'
      }
    },
    firestore: {
        devices: db.collection('devices')
    },
  };
```

My expectation is devices should `id` property as [vuefire docs](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#using-the-data-bound-by-vuefire).

But array `this.devices` didn't have `id` field even if I check it exist it console.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, every document already has `id` attribute, but it's [non-enumerable](http://zduck.com/2013/non-enumerable-properties-in-javascript/)

> Any document bound by Vuexfire will retain it's id in the database as
>   a non-enumerable, read-only property. This makes it easier to write
>   changes and allows you to only copy the data using the spread operator
>   or Object.assign.

You can access `id` directly using `device.id`. But when passing to `vue-tables-2`、devices is copied and lost `id` non-enumerable attribute.

I think you can workaround using `computed` property

```
computed: {
  devicesWithId() {
    if (!this.devices) {
      return []
    }
    return this.devices.map(device => {
      ...device,
      id: device.id
    })
  }
}
```

Then, please try using `devicesWithId` in vue-tables-2 instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you let me know how can I pass new `deviceWithId`.    ` return this.devices.map(device => { let newDevice = {}; newDevice = Object.assign({}, device); newDevice.id = device.id; newDevices.push(newDevice)}`.  I checked device.id has it's doc id.  But stuck at pass these.